# Using Valid annotation to validate file in spring java

Tags: java, spring-boot

So i have the following set up in spring boot, and the validation handler does get triggered but im not sure how to test my controller in unit tests. The validator seems to get injected in and used. Is there anyway i can mock the validator?

```
   @Validated
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/test”)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TestController {

    @PostMapping(“/test”)
    public ResponseEntity<ApiResponse<Void>> importFile(
            @ValidFile @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

       return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CREATED);

    }



@Documented
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER, TYPE_USE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {FileValidator.class})
public @interface ValidFile {

    String message() default ”error somwehere” ;

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}


@RestControllerAdvice
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class ValidationExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)
    protected ValidationErrorResponse onConstraintValidationException(ConstraintViolationException e) {
        ValidationErrorResponse error = new ValidationErrorResponse();
        for (ConstraintViolation violation : e.getConstraintViolations()) {
            error.getViolations().add(new Violation(violation.getPropertyPath().toString(), violation.getMessage()));
        }
        return error;
    }
..
}

public class FileValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidFile, MultipartFile> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(ValidFile constraintAnnotation) { }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(MultipartFile multipartFile, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        String contentType = multipartFile.getContentType();
        return isSupportedContentType(contentType);
    }

    private boolean isSupportedContentType(String contentType) {
        return Arrays.stream(SUPPORTED_CONTENT_TYPES).anyMatch(contentType::equals);
    }
}
```

I have tried using:

```
context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
```

but if there are no violations than it flags as an error.. anyone have any ideas why this is happening?.. i keep getting the following:

Request processing failed: jakarta.validation.ValidationException: HV000033: At least one custom message must be created if the default error message gets disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can test your controller in several ways. I would call the first method more common for testing the web layer in spring-boot application - using the [`@WebMvcTest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcTest.html) annotation. From its docs:

> Using this annotation will disable full auto-configuration and instead
> apply only configuration relevant to MVC tests (i.e. @Controller,
> @ControllerAdvice, @JsonComponent, Converter/GenericConverter, Filter,
> WebMvcConfigurer and HandlerMethodArgumentResolver beans but not
> @Component, @Service or @Repository beans)

But in this case the validation is also enabled, which is good because we can also check our responses for invalid request bodies, so I would advise using this approach:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockMultipartFile;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.multipart;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

@WebMvcTest(controllers = TestController.class)
class TestControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    void testImportFileValidFile() throws Exception {
        // valid file
        MockMultipartFile file = new MockMultipartFile("file", "test.txt", "text/plain", "Valid_data".getBytes());

        mockMvc.perform(multipart("/api/v1/test/test")
                        .file(file)
                        .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA))
                .andExpect(status().isCreated());
    }

    @Test
    void testImportFileInvalidFile() throws Exception {
        // invalid file
        MockMultipartFile file = new MockMultipartFile("file", "test.txt", "text/plain", "Invalid_data!".getBytes());

        mockMvc.perform(multipart("/api/v1/test/test")
                        .file(file)
                        .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA))
                .andExpect(status().isUnprocessableEntity());
    }
}
```

However, if you want to test the controller class without any spring context at all, you can of course write a simple poor unit test. In this case validation isn't triggered indeed:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockMultipartFile;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

class TestControllerTest {

    private final TestController testController = new TestController();

    @Test
    void testImportFileWithValidFile() {
        MockMultipartFile mockMultipartFile = new MockMultipartFile("file", "test.txt", "text/plain", "Hello, World!".getBytes());

        ResponseEntity<ApiResponse<Void>> response = testController.importFile(mockMultipartFile);

        assertEquals(HttpStatus.CREATED, response.getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

Comment: What if my validator was autowiring and using other beans. Could i mock them. I attempted to mock them using mockbean but for some reason setting expectations doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @user1555190, if you use WebMvcTest, then you can use `@MockBean(YourValidator.class)`, if simple test, then `@Mock` on your validator. If you want, add minimal example to your question, I will update an answer

Comment: @user1555190, also if my answer was helpful and acceptable for you, click accept it as answer.

Comment: @user1555190, was this answer useful for you? It's always good to leave at least some feedback, as this will show that you respect the community members who are helping YOU resolve YOUR issue